# How to set disabled field column on grid depending on record value (EXTJS)?

Tags: extjs

Hy, i new to use Extjs.. 
i have a gridpanel like this:

```
  var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1
  });

  var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: myStore,
        plugins: [cellEditing],
        columns: [  
                {dataIndex: 'colid', hidden: true},
                {text: "Name", dataIndex: 'colname', sortable: true},
                {text: "Info", dataIndex: 'colinfo', sortable: true},
                {text: "Value", dataIndex: 'colvalue',
                 editor: {
                   xtype: 'textfield'
                 }
            }
        ]
    });
```

Now i want to set editor to null (like column colinfo,colname and colid) column **colvalue** when **colinfo** value is "Can not edit this value!!".. 
How i to configure that's condition??

Answer (score 0):

you can use the renderer function for which column you want to disable. Based on the record value in the function you can set the textfield to be disabled.